# Issue with installing R package on R studio

Tags: r, installation, package, raster

I work on Rstudio and my version() result is:

```
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          3.1                         
year           2016                        
month          06                          
day            21                          
svn rev        70800                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
nickname       Bug in Your Hair
```

I downloaded the latest version this morning from the web to have the last update.
On this, I can not install the package "raster":

```
> install.packages('raster')
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/florent/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘raster’ is not available (for R version 3.3.1)
```

I have checked many help online but I can´t find the solution. I did an update of R (to 4.0.2) with which this raster package is working.

Anyone has a solution for this? It begins to be tricky...

Thanks!

Comment: (Is there a good reason to use an acient R version?) The raster package depends on R (≥ 3.5.0). If you want to use it with an older R version, you'll need an older version of raster, which you can get from the CRAN archive: https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/raster/ Obviously, you'd need to build it from source. Also, it's possible that you would also need to install older versions of sp and/or Rcpp. You'd need to test that.

Comment: So do you mean that raster if not available for Rstudio for now? Thanks

Comment: RStudio is almost irrelevant here. Package installation is an R issue. And I'm saying that R 3.3.1 is too old to use the current version of raster with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you updated *RStudio*, but not *R*. RStudio is a program to make it easier to use R. So what you need to do is install the current version of *R*. As you can see from your `version`, you are using a version from 2016. That is ancient in the R world.

In RStudio you can look under *Tools / Global Options / General / R version* and perhaps change the **R** version if multiple versions are available.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually updated R, I got R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22). So it seems that I have to update R from Rstudio? I thought Rstudio was just using the R version installed on the computer.

Comment: I just reinstalled it again  from https://rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/#download and I got R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)

Comment: Found the issue. I removed all the apps files from R and now it works. R studio was using an ancient version! Great, thanks